# convert a string to an operator

Tags: wpf, vb.net, operator-keyword, type-conversion

In my VB.Net 4.5 WPF app I have 3 text boxes for the user to enter the following:

1. txtFirstNumber
2. txtOperator
3. txtSecondNumber

PROBLEM: I find I cannot convert the operator string into an actual mathematical operator, because there is no data type for an operator.

I cannot use + or & or val or eval to calculate: txtFirstNumber txtOperator txtSecondNumber

For example: if the user enters 12 as the firstNumber, + as operator and 5 as the secondNumber then I want to automatically calculate 12 + 5 and place the answer in a label named CalculateAnswer.

If the user enters something different, I want the calculation to still be made. Even if they enter a double as one of the numbers.

So I need help! Here's my code:

```
    Dim CalcAnswer As Double
    Try
        Dim first As Double = CDbl(txtFirstNumber.Text)
        Dim op As String = txtOperator.Text
        Dim second As Double = CDbl(txtSecondNumber.Text)
        CalcAnswer = Eval(first & op & second)
        CalculateAnswer.Content = CStr(CalcAnswer)
    Catch CalcError As Exception
        MsgBox(CalcError.Message)
    End Try
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your `Eval()` function look like?

Comment: Also: you may want to use Decimal instead of Double for this.

Comment: Thanks Joel - I dont have an Eval function. I was told by Google that Eval was short for Evaluate which was already defined. But it doesn't work.

Comment: `Eval()` is not part of .Net, and for good reason (Eval() functions are big gaping security holes). You'll have to write this part yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
Try
    Dim first As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(txtFirstNumber.Text)
    Dim second As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(txtSecondNumber.Text)
    CalculateAnswer.Content = Eval(first, second, txtOperator.Text).ToString()
Catch CalcError As Exception
    MsgBox(CalcError.Message)
End Try

'...

Function Add(ByVal a As Decimal, ByVal b As Decimal) As Decimal
   Return a + b
End Function

Function Subtract(ByVal a As Decimal, ByVal b As Decimal) As Decimal
   Return a - b
End Function

Function Multiply(ByVal a As Decimal, ByVal b As Decimal) As Decimal
   Return a * b
End Function

Function Divide(ByVal a As Decimal, ByVal b As Decimal) As Decimal
   Return a / b
End Function

Function Eval(ByVal a As Decimal, ByVal b As Decimal, ByVal Operator As String) As Decimal
   Operator = Operator.Trim()
   Select Operator
      Case "+"
        Return Add(a, b)
      Case "-"
        Return Subtract(a, b)
      Case "*","x"
        Return Multiply(a, b)
      Case "/"
         Return Divide(a, b)
      Case Else 
          Throw New InvalidArgumentException("Did not recognize operator: " & Operator)
   End Select
End Function
```

Comment: maybe check that b is not 0 for the Divide function?

Comment: Gosh thats a lot of extra work for something I thought would be really simple!

Comment: Thanks Plutonix - divide by zero is a danger.

Comment: @Plutonix And do what, throw another InvalidArgument? The existing error handling from the OP's code is good for this already.

Comment: Thanks Joel, after a tweak your code works! 
[Operator is a keyword so I cant use that. The invalidArgumentException didn't work either, so I used a try catch block instead. All good. Thanks!]